# RShiny Render DT table not showing

Tags: shiny, dt

I am trying to make a 4 tab app with an introduction and then 3 tabs which display a table with a side bar with some options but I cannot get the table to display.

I have stripped it down to the bare bones, and replaced my real data with some generated data but I still cannot get the table to display and am not sure what i am missing or if it is simply a syntax error I can't find.

This is the current code:

```
# Load required libraries
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

data <- data.frame(
  Name = c("John", "Alice", "Bob", "Eve", "Charlie"),
  Age = c(30, 25, 35, 28, 40),
  City = c("New York", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "San Francisco", "Miami"),
  Grade = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B")
)

########################################INTRO PANEL
intro_panel <- tabPanel(
  "Overview",
  titlePanel("This is the title"),
  img(src = "images/infographic.png", width = "100%"),
  p("This app does....."),
  p(a(href = "[url]", "[Link text]"))
)

##################Side bar content defined
sidebar_content <- sidebarPanel(
) #end of sidebar Panel

############################################MAIN PANEL DEFINED
main_content <- mainPanel(
  p("Does this show up?"),
  DTOutput('table_top'), 
  style="font-size:80%"
)#endof main panel



#########################REST OF THE PANELS
second_panel <- tabPanel(
  "Second",
  titlePanel("Second Level"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebar_content, main_content
  )
)

third_panel <- tabPanel(
  "Third",
  titlePanel("Third Level"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebar_content, main_content
  )
)

fourth_panel <- tabPanel(
  "Fourth",
  titlePanel("Fourth Tab"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebar_content, main_content
  )
)



############################DEFINE THE WHOLE UserInterface

ui <- navbarPage(
  "Title",
  tabsetPanel(
    intro_panel,
    second_panel,
    third_panel,
    fourth_panel
  )
)

##################################SERVER
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table_top <- DT::renderDT(data)
}

##################################SHINY APP
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You are using `main_content` in all the four panels.  That means `outputID` of `DTOutput()` is not unique.

Comment: Ah thanks so much, I just copied my first tab to attempt to generate the second. I have given them all unique names now and it works. Thanks